# What is the meaning of "see" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This sentence from the
[oxford learners dictionary:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hedge-fund?q=hedge+fund)

At the definition of a "hedge fund" example. I couldn't understand what is the meaning of "sees" in this sentence.

**hedge fund:**
​ an investment fund involving a group of people who take high risks with their investments in order to try and make a lot of money

> This month **sees** the launch of a hedge fund aimed at private investors.

I think it has the same meaning as in the following sentence but I couldn't be sure:

> This summer **has seen** unusually high temperatures.

Could you please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary, Oxford Learner Dictionary definition of "see",
[Oxford Dictionary "see" 16](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/see_1?q=see)
see something: **to be the time when an event happens**

*Next year sees the centenary of Saint-Saëns' death.*
*The twentieth century saw dramatic changes in most areas of life.*

So, yes, your are right about the meaning.
It has the sense of "this is/was the time when we see/saw", but the "seeing" is transferred from the experiencers to the time of the event.

Comment: I also see `see` used this way for not just time but also space. `Germany sees a spike in coronavirus` is a recent headline from the New York Times.

Comment: @SonNguyen Yes, that's shown as definition 17 in Oxford Dictionary, just after the 16 that I cited. "see" 17 to be the place where an event happens

Comment: @SonNguyen  How do you put that highlighting in your comment?

Comment: Jack O'Flaherty: I see, hope it's a fact worth mentioning though. Use the backticks \`\`, I prefer it to quotes as I don't have to press Shift.

Comment: @SonNguyen `Thank you!`